# Editable ComboBox selects first entered character

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox

I am having issues with a `ComboBox`selecting the first entered character, which then causes the a problem where the second entered character overwrites the first one.

EDIT: A small explanation of what I an trying to do. 
I have set up the `ComboBox` to act as an autocomplete control. When I enter a character, I am using `CollectionView` class to filter any names that match each entered character. Upon entered text the `ComboBox` drop down menu needs to open up, which is why I am binding to `IsDropDownOpen`.  [This is how it is supposed to look here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43727449/6283475)

This is beyond me, I can't research what I need to do to stop this behavior.

Here is a screen shot of what I mean.

[image]

This is the ComboBox XAML:

```
<ComboBox Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleHidden}" 
      DisplayMemberPath="FullName" SelectedValuePath="Key"
      IsTextSearchEnabled="False" 
      IsEditable="True" 
      StaysOpenOnEdit="True" 
      Text="{Binding Path=EnteredText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Employees}" 
      SelectedItem="{Binding UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Path=SelectedEmployee}" 
      IsDropDownOpen="{Binding IsDropDown}">
</ComboBox>
```

EDIT: I have narrowed it down to this, `IsDropDown = true;`, commenting this out fixes the issue. But I need the drop down when editing the `ComboBox`

In the `EnteredText` property

```
private string _enteredText;

public string EnteredText
{
    get { return _enteredText; }
    set
    {
        _enteredText = value;
        Filter(value);
        IsDropDown = true;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}


public bool IsDropDown { get; set; }
```

Comment: Do you change the Employees collection when TextInput goes on?

Comment: You're doing something in the view model.  There should be no logic other than INPC in the property setters.  Show them.

Comment: @Mishka, yes I am, I am using `CollectionView` to filter the collection. But, removing the method did nothing.

Comment: @Will, Miska's comment got me thinking and when commenting out `IsDropDown = true;` the issue goes away. Why would setting the dropdown to true cause this?

Comment: Is there a `V` item in the list? It is almost like the control accepts a `V` but checks, finds nothing, then removes the character to start afresh.

Comment: You mean "IsDropDownOpen"?  Why were you binding to it?  What were you doing?  All this stuff that's not in your question... You really should create a small prototype that isolates the issue when you run into situations like this.  If it doesn't make it obviously clear what the problem is (which it does 75% of the time for me!), you can put the entire repro in a question and get correct answers much quicker.  All this is guessing and weaving bamboo into cargo planes at this point.

Comment: @Will, I mean when I comment out the code of setting the `IsDropDownOpen` to true, I get this behavior. And I did not know this until I posted the question and got some comments that something like this could happen.

Comment: @OmegaMan, Yes, when I enter `V` it is automatically selected for some reason, so upon entering the next character, the `V` get overwritten. This is not acceptable.

Comment: I know its not acceptable, but you didn't answer the question. Is there a V item in the list?

Comment: @OmegaMan, you have lost me. I explained what is happening in the earlier comment.  If you are asking if there is a `V` in the collection, then partially yes. The logic behind the `ComboBox` filters by using LINQ and `StatsWith` and there are names that start with `V`.

Comment: I would love to know the reason for the down vote? Won't hold my breath though.

Comment: @Will, I missed a question of yours, I am binding the the `IsDropDownOpen` b/c when I enter text, I want the `ComboBox` to open.

Comment: UI concerns in the view model.  Avoid at all costs, as it does a mischief.  Custom controls/user controls with UI logic controlling things like this are always the best thing to do.  Odd, I'd think the automatic opening of the dropdown would be baked into the control, but I've never done exactly the same as you did here.  Remember--minimum prototype is always your best initial bet to finding a solution, and helps you make a very clear and answerable question.

Comment: I would create a simple test program with a set of preloaded data and see if the same happens. If it works, you can post the simple program back here for us to figure out. If it doesn't, it shows that you have something else *blocking*(?) and that may help you find a solution. Not being able to see your code hampers a true response from us. Maybe the non English characters or OS keyboard is causing the issue? By creating a test program, we can see what if any that has an effect.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I solved this doing a hack, but it will have to do until I can figure out why this behavior is happening.

I created an `KeyUpEvent` Event in the constructor,

```
EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(TextBox), TextBox.KeyUpEvent,
            new RoutedEventHandler(DeselectText));
```

Then in the `Handler` I just deselected the text.

```
private void DeselectText(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   var textBox = e.OriginalSource as TextBox;
   if (textBox == null) return;
   if (textBox.Text.Length >= 2) return;
   textBox.SelectionLength = 0;
   textBox.SelectionStart = 1;
}
```

I know this is a hack, but I have no choice until the correct solution is posted.

This is how it looks with the hack.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Consider this as another solution. It mights resove the side effect of above mentioned problem.

I am expecting the TemplateChild to have the Name (PART_EditableTextBox). If you are changing the name in the Template then please do the necessary changes here as well.

```
    private TextBox EditableTextBox => (TextBox)GetTemplateChild("PART_EditableTextBox");

    protected override void OnDropDownOpened(EventArgs e)
    {
        EditableTextBox.Select(Text.Length, 0);
        base.OnDropDownOpened(e);
    }
```